# showing loading element in vue only when needed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I have the vue code below:

```
    '<div v-if="team_members && team_members.length > 0">' +
    'screen1'
    '</div>' +
    '<div v-else>' +
    '<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="spinner">' +
    '<circle class="ring" cx="25" cy="25" r="10"/>' +
    '<circle class="line" cx="25" cy="25" r="10"/>' +
    '</svg>' +
    'Screen is loading.' +
    '</div>' +
```

As you can see in the code above, I am using conditional rendering to only render screen1 if team_members has a value which is passed as a prop. Note: team_members takes a while to load as I receiving data from API which is why I am using else currently to show screen is loading and then when team_members populates, the if loop is triggered. The conditional aspect works fine: it shows screen1 if team_members is there and shows loading if not. My next concern is that I do not want to show the loading elements if team_members truly does not have any value. I just want it to say 'No Screen Available'. Is there anyway I can put in a check to see if a component is still loading or maybe even a timer. Usually team_members will load in 1-2 minutes, so I could put a timer check there.

Let me know how I could do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using vue-else-if directive. You could slip this right between the v-if and v-else directives. The below code should work for you.

```
<div v-if="team_members && team_members.length>0">Screen 1</div>
<div v-else-if="!team_members">No Screen Available</div>
<div v-else>Screen is loading</div>
```